# async.map node js code function(err, results) never called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function in node:

```
async.map(results[Object.keys(results)[1]][0], function(value, callback) {
     /* GET - status */
     status(value, results[Object.keys(results)[1]][1], results[Object.keys(results)[1]][2][(results[Object.keys(results)[1]][0]).indexOf(value)])
     }, function(err, results) {
         console.log('function finished called...')
     })
```

function runs fine and all is working except that this code is never triggered:

```
}, function(err, results) {
     console.log('function finished called...')
 })
```

This i need to be triggered and get results and error bit is never called...so i could not fiqure why?

Comment: You need to send the result using `callback`. `callback(error)` or `callback(null,data)`.

Comment: Thanks....i forget to callback...i added it and now it works...thanks